# Payments made through iOS Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, mobile-website, google-checkout

I know there is IAP for native apps, regarding the iOS, but does this effect websites (I will explain)?

I have an e-commerce store (standard website) and my client wants to be sell on Facebook alongside promotions etc.

Within the configurations for 'Mobile Web' on developer.facebook.com there is this line `If your app accepts payments through any non-iOS approved service it will be restricted on iOS.
Learn more.`.

> 1. What exactly does this mean?
> 2. Is Mobile Web not intended for configuring web apps, so they appear on iOS Facebook.
> 3. Where can I find a list of approved payment providers?

Or have I missed the point altogether? I am using Google Checkout API to process payments from my custom cart.

Any light someone can shed on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the answer:
This is a legal requirement by Apple that is passed on by Facebook.
Apples does not allow any app to perform payments not through its payment mechanism.
Facebook iOS App is bound by the same licence.
Since Facebook is an (iOS) App that runs other (facebook) Apps - the apps inside the Facebook (iOS) App should abide the same licence.

I agree this is not convenient as it makes you deal with more than one payment service just for you to get to iPhone.

--franji